# whats the difference between the motul c2 and c1 chain lube oil?thanks in advance

Tags: noise, chain

whats the difference between the motul c2 and c1 chain lube oil.thanks in advance.
I have been wondering to buy the chain lube oil,when i came across these two oils. I would like to know the differences.

Comment: Is there a specific application you are looking at these for?

Answer (score 1):

According to their web site and the technical data sheet for each one.  The C1 is a clean and degrease spray.  Where as C2 is a spray lubricant.  They also have C3, C4 and C5.  [MOTUL ALL PRODUCTS MAINTENANCE AND CARE](https://www.motul.com/us/en-us/products/oils-lubricants?f%5Bapplication%5D=142&f%5Brange%5D=30)